# Android - How to import android.support.design.testutils in my project

Tags: android, unit-testing, tdd, material-design, material-components

I have seen that there exists a set of testing components in the material-components-android library:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/tests/javatests/android/support/design/testutils

I would like to use *TestUtilsActions.java* to enrich the available set of espresso testing actions like `click()`, `typeText(aString)`. It seems like I would be able to have `setEnabled(enabled)`, `setClickable(clickable)`,  etc.

I have imported the library in my *build.gradle* file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

But still I'm not able to reach that `testutils` package:
[image]

Can anyone tell me what should I do?

Comment: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android in this project they have used testutills

Comment: @RajeshNasit I know, please see the link I have included in the question.

Comment: oh sorry but this might help https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner.html and https://developer.android.com/training/testing/samples.html